# Why does this line not instantiate a class?

Tags: python, class, torch

I am a python beginner going over a tutorial on neural networks and the PY torch module.  I don't quite understand the behavior of this line.

```
import torch.nn as nn

loss = nn.MSELoss()

print(loss)

>>MSELoss()
```

Since nn.MSELoss is a class, why does calling it to the variable loss not instantiate it as a class object?  What type of code is in the class MSELoss that allows it to achieve this behavior?

Comment: What makes you think this doesn't create an instance?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/loss.py#L368) type of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print some object you're actually calling its `__str__` method in Python or if it isn't defined then `__repr__` (from *representation*).

In your case, it's about *normal* class, but its `__repr__` [has been overriden](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/10c4b98ade8349d841518d22f19a653a939e260c/torch/nn/modules/module.py):

```
def __repr__(self):
    # We treat the extra repr like the sub-module, one item per line
    extra_lines = []
    extra_repr = self.extra_repr()
    # empty string will be split into list ['']
    if extra_repr:
        extra_lines = extra_repr.split('\n')
    child_lines = []
    for key, module in self._modules.items():
        mod_str = repr(module)
        mod_str = _addindent(mod_str, 2)
        child_lines.append('(' + key + '): ' + mod_str)
    lines = extra_lines + child_lines

    main_str = self._get_name() + '('
    if lines:
        # simple one-liner info, which most builtin Modules will use
        if len(extra_lines) == 1 and not child_lines:
            main_str += extra_lines[0]
        else:
            main_str += '\n  ' + '\n  '.join(lines) + '\n'

    main_str += ')'
    return main_str
```

Answer (score 0):

It does instantiate a class. However that class implements the special `__call__` method which allows you to use the call operator `()` on it as if it were a function. It also implements the `__repr__` method which customizes how it appears when you print it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html), `nn.MSELoss()` creates a criterion that measures the mean squared error, that you can use this way:

```
loss = nn.MSELoss()
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.randn(3, 5)
output = loss(input, target)
output.backward()
```

You can check that `loss` is an `MSELoss` class:

```
print(type(loss).__name__)
>>> MSELoss
```